# Dynamic properties in spring annotations (@ComponentScan)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got following spring header in my class

```
@Service
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.package1", "com.package2", "com.package3"})
public class SomeContainer { }
```

Do you have a possibility to extract this packages ("com.package1, 2 ,3 and etc) into separate property file but to keep annotation driven style?

Comment: No, annotations need arguments to be constants. Use spring profiles instead or invoke component scanning programmatically.

Comment: @Stefan ok, can i replace this annotation by spring xml configuration and use propertyplaceholderconfigurer instead?

Comment: Did you try `@ComponentScan("${scan.packages}")` (for example)?

Comment: @DaveSyer how i will inject this variable?

Comment: What do you mean? Spring injects it.

Comment: @DaveSyer it should be a correct place to inject it - it could be placeholder or property, but how you can inject multiple values?

Answer (score 3):

What the previous poster was trying to say and I'll clarify this. My main app class looks like this:

```
@Import(AppConfig.class)
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

And the Appconfig like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "${scan.packages}")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppConfig {
}
```

The application.properties file is located in the src/main/resources folder, where it is automatically looked for and it contains my scan.packages line:

```
scan.packages=com.mypackage
```

If you run this from the main method in the App class, everything will be configured appropriately.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: if you will add more packages to scan.packages like "com.mypackage1, com.mypackage2" it won't work

Comment: @ServerSideCat The following line worked for me (in application.properties)
`scan.package=observerspring,external.observerspring.second`

Answer (score -1):

try to add your properties into a file for example application.properties, and inject them in your config class

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
 public class ConfigApp { 

 }


 @ComponentScan("${scan.packages}")
```

Comment: @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties") is for injecting propertises file and to use this properties use @ComponentScan("${scan.packages}").

Before that you must have a file application.properties who contains properties as key, value for example :

scan.packages1=com.paackage1
scan.packages2=com.paackage2
scan.packages3=com.paackage3

Comment: You don't need a `@PropertySource` in a Spring Boot application.

Comment: Yes don't need a @PropertySource if you have a file named **application.properties** but if you have another name, you must use it to inject externalized properties

Comment: @tcharaf you are not able to use multiple values for PropertySource. It is not possible to get [ packages=com.example1,com.example2 ] for it, only one value